# Add grid to custom tab magento admin

Tags: magento-1.7, admin

i am trying to display a custom grid on an extra tab added on the product page.
I managed to add the custom tab successfully using this tutorial:

http://mydons.com/how-to-add-custom-tabs-to-magento-customer-edit-page/

Then i used this documentation to make a custom table in database and set up models etc.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table#template_design

However, i'm not able to figure out how to add a grid to the new created tab.

I did not paste all of my code here, but if you need any additional information, please ask.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Running through the entirety of creating a tab and adding a grid to it would be a pretty big, probably multi part answer.  It would be nice to see what you have done so far - that way you will probably get more response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your right content is displayed in a phtml (app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customertab/action.phtml). In your phtml file you could display your grid using

```
<?php 
  echo $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('<module>/adminhtml_<path>_grid')
            ->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: this was indeed the issue, i tried tis before, but i had an error in the path :D, thanks